# A river boat can travel at 20km per hour in still water. The boat travels 30km upstream?

Tags: calculus

A river boat can travel a 20km per hour in still water. The boat travels 30km upstream against the current then turns around and travels the same distance back with the current. IF the total trip took 7.5 hours, what is the speed of the current? Solve this question algebraically as well as graphically..

I started the Algebra Solution: starting with this 
x=(Vstill-Vcurrent)t,(When goes up stream)
x=(Vstill Vcurrent) t2( when it goes back stream....

I have the same question on a quiz in 1 hours and I need to know how to do this please show a solution :D thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the solution by Daryl, we travel a distance of $30$ at speed $20+v$, and the same distance at speed $20-v$. So the total time taken is 
$$\frac{30}{20+v}+\frac{30}{20-v}.$$
This simplifies to 
$$\frac{1200}{400-v^2}.$$
The total time is $7.5$, and therefore
$$\frac{1200}{400-v^2}=7.5.$$
This can be rewritten as
$$400-v^2=\frac{1200}{7.5}=160.$$
Thus $v^2=240$.

Comment: so9 how many km/h ?

Comment: The square root of $240$, approximately $15.49$ km/hr.

Comment: any I dea how I will do this graphically if I wasy to say use a x min -30 x max of 30 y min of -10 and y max of 10

Comment: any idea how to do it graphically

Comment: Here is a suggestion, definitely not imaginative. We have the equation $\frac{30}{20+v}+\frac{30}{20-v}=7.5$. If we have a graphing calculator, we can graph the function $y=\frac{30}{20+x}+\frac{30}{20-x}-7.5$, and use the graphing calculator display to find approximately the $x$ for which $f(x)=0$. This is not really necessary, since the equation is not hard to solve algebraically, but in a more complicated situation it could be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**

1. We know that distance = speed $\times$ time. So let $t_1$ be the time travelling upstream and $t_2$ be the time travelling downstream. Also let $v$ be the velocity of the current in the river. Then you have
   $$\begin{aligned}
   30&=(20-v)t_1&\text{[upstream travel]}, \\
   30&=(20+v)t_2&\text{[downstream travel]}. \end{aligned}$$
2. You also have the total time, $t_1+t_2=7.5$.
3. You can solve this system of equations for the three unknown variables. I calculate them to be $t_1=\frac{3}{4}(5+\sqrt{15}),t_2=\frac{3}{4}(5-\sqrt{15}), v=4\sqrt{15}$.

Comment: so the speed of the current is 332km/h I got?

Comment: @StevenJohn:  that would be an extremely fast river-over 200 miles/hour?  I don't think so.

Comment: what did you get?

Comment: what did you get?